# How to update only changed fields using MVVM and EF Core in Blazor app?

Tags: mvvm, entity-framework-core, blazor, change-tracking

I have a blazor server app with EF Core as a data access layer.

1. When user visits a page, I load entities from DbContext, fill the VM with the data and dispose the db context.

   ```
   using var dbContext = DbContextFactory.CreateDbContext();
   var entity = dbContext.Products.Find(Id);
   ViewModel = new ViewModel { Id = entity.Id, Name = entity.Name.. }
   ```
2. When users clicks "Save" button, I load the entities again from fresh DbContext instance, copy all editable field from VM to the entities and call DbContext.SaveChanges.

   ```
   using var dbContext = DbContextFactory.CreateDbContext();
   var entity = dbContext.Products.Find(Id);
   entity.Name = ViewModel.Name; .....
   dbContext.SaveChanges();
   ```

**I would like to avoid copying all fields from VMs to entities**, because it will overwrite all changes made to the DB meanwhile. **I would like to update only fields edited by user**.

Implementing a change tracking in a ViewModel, especially in a more complex hierarchical structure is a non trivial tasks.

How can I do this effectively in a Blazor app? Especially without unnecessary DRY violations.

Comment: Just include in ViewModel which fields are changed and update only these fields.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv: What about child collection, added or removed items? I don't want to write`if (vm.fieldChanged)  entity.Field = vm.Field` on every possible field, and to write the change tracking manually for every field, because that would be a lot of repetitive code with lot of space for errors.

Comment: Yeah, we are lazy, I know. But who will write that instead of us? You can use https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-c-source-generators/ and generate ViewModels which tracks changes. I have not seen framework(library) which can do that for you and send information via network and then apply graph changes automatically...

Comment: You could serialize the model when the page is loaded, then deserialize it on update and compare properties with the updated model one-by-one using reflection.  This way it could be a generic procedure that could work for all of your models.